# How to extract Prisma client extension types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

I am defining a Prisma client extension as such:

```
const prismaClient = _prismaClient.$extends({
  query: {
    company: {
      update: async ({ args, query }) => {
        if (args.data?.status === CompanyStatus.DECLINED) {
          args.data.user = {
            update: {
              accountLocked:
                AccountLockedReason.COMPANY_DECLINED,
            },
          }
        }

        return query(args)
      },
    },
  },
})
```

The TypeScript types for `$extends` seem to be working perfectly, although if I have a look at the generated types in `node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts`, the output is extremely complex.

I would like to organise my client extensions in a separate dir, for the sake of maintainability:

```
// prismaClient.ts
const prismaClient = _prismaClient.$extends({
  query: {
    company: companyExtensions,
  },
})

// companyExtensions.ts
export const companyExtensions: NeedsType = {
  update: async ({ args, query }) => {
    if (args.data?.status === CompanyStatus.DECLINED) {
      args.data.user = {
        update: {
          accountLocked:
            AccountLockedReason.COMPANY_DECLINED,
        },
      }
    }

    return query(args)
  },
}
```

I have struggled for over an hour to try and isolate types for a separated `companyExtensions` object. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
type CompanyExtensions = Parameters<typeof prismaClient['$extends']>[0]
```

I know that Prisma has a special `defineExtension` function, but it seems to be targeted towards distribution of generalised client extensions and does not contain specific `arg` typing for my models themselves.

Would appreciate any help that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it like this:

```
type ExtensionArgs = Extract<
  Parameters<typeof _prismaClient.$extends>[0],
  { name?: string }
>
```